# View is loaded from nib but is not visible?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, xib, nib

I create two custom views using nib files and I create one instance for each class and then I added the two views to my main view , the first view is added and the second is loaded but not visible.

I load the views from the nib file using the following class method

```
class func instanceFromNib() -> CustomView {
    let view = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CustomView", owner: self, options: nil).first as! CustomView
    return view
}
```

I need help to figure out what is going wrong with the second view.

Comment: try it 
`let view = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("CustomView", owner: self, options: nil).[0]`

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
 view.autoresizingMask = .None
```

Comment: Works for me.) @Basheer_CAD can you explain how did you come to this solution?

Comment: I faced the same issue for a long time. Looks like xcode adds unnecessary constraints causing the view to collapse to 0 height or width, the solution above removes all interface builders default constraints. Now you should be responsible for adding or removing constraints programmatically